# Is it possible to use the Volume Notifications from Gnome Shell in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, notification

I somehow had them working before in 11.10 but I don't really remember what did I do back then other than activating "load Gnome components on start up" in the XFCE's settings manager.

I've tried the same in 12.04 but doesn't seem to do anything, I specifically ask for the Volume notifications as other notifications used `notify-osd` or `xfce4-notifyd` but the volume one was Gnome's (I found that later) As far as I know it uses `notification-daemon`but installing it instead of the other two doesn't give me the correct notifications.

I'm using XFCE 4.10

This is what I get from running `gnome-settings-daemon` in the Terminal.

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:3841): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1137:14: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3841): WARNING **: You can only run one xsettings manager at a time; exiting

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3841): WARNING **: Unable to start xsettings manager: Could not initialize xsettings manager.

** (process:3849): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3841): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3841): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: ***No, You cannot use it in XFCE***.

You correctly said, Gnome-Shell's volume notification is it's own and it uses `notification-daemon`. The [`notification-daemon`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/notification-daemon) is a program used to display the pop-up notification. You can use "notification-daemon" is a generic name for any daemon providing notification. For XFCE it is `xfce4-notifyd`.

Gnome-Shell uses `gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer` program which resides in `/usr/lib/gnome-shell/` to give the Volume notification. As this is a very internal component of gnome-shell (it runs automatically with gnome-shell) you cannot use it without installing gnome-shell or using it.

To see that this indeed is responsible for Volume notification, temporarily disable it by renaming it to `gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer.bak` file

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer.back
```

Then restart gnome-shell with the command `gnome-shell --replace` from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> graphical command box. Try mounting a drive and you'll see there is no notification for mounted drive.

To restore back the file, use this command to rename it to original name

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer.bak /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-hotplug-sniffer
```

Answer (score 0):

Run gnome-settings-daemon in the background. It handles special keys, keyboard layouts, and the like.

EDIT:

Should've tested that before posting.

You can get gnome-settings-daemon running with:

```
$ killall xfsettingsd && gnome-settings-daemon
```

Note that this will set your GTK theme to the default old-school GNOME2 look. But you will have your GNOME-style volume pop-ups.

Comment: I get errors, it shuts down when running, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Nope, still get the regular notifications but It does default to the Raleigh theme.

Comment: Bummer.  I actually get the little GNOME keyboard / volume popups on my setup.

Comment: `gnome-settings-daemon` runs in Unity also, but we do not get that popup in Unity. So, it definitely isn't gnome-settings-daemon